# unresolved external symbol _CLSID_ScenicIntentUIFramework with GUID

Tags: c++, windows, windows-7, sdk, ribbon

I'm trying to build a ribbon app in visual studio and I got that linker error. After looking through the headers, I noticed that CLSID_ScenicIntentFramework is defined as extern const CLSID. The think is, I can't seem to figure out which library I need to link to (or other header i need to import?).

I'd really appreciated some help too.

Afternote: I noticed that in addtion to scenicintent.h, there is a scenicintent.idl, but if I include this into my project I get a slew of errors. Is there a proper way to include idl files, and would that fix my issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Often times, you need to link to an import library (.lib file) that contains the definitions of the class ids and interface ids for the library you are using. Alternatively, you can use the `__uuidof` keyword that can get the associated GUID for an attributed object (a class or interface).

```
__uuidof(ScenicIntentFramework) // this should be the same thing
```